# Indented JQuery Selectable List - when number of indentation levels are not known beforehand

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a selectable list with parent/child/grandchild/... indentations. Please see below:

http://jsfiddle.net/hphvpxuo/1/

**HTML code:**

```
<li class="level-1">
    <div>Parent 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li>
            <div>Child 1.1 - consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>Child 1.2 - Integer nec odio</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.level-1 {
    margin-left: .25em;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.level-2 {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

**Javascript code:**

[Please see jsfiddle]

Is it possible to dynamically define CSS stylings based on the depth of children you have? In the example above, I only have parent/child levels shown (level-1 and level-2 only) - and I have defined "margin-left" appropriately for these two levels.

But, the actual number of levels can only be determined during runtime - e.g. I may need 5 levels of indentation (up to "level-5") or more. Is it possible to dynamically define indentations (through CSS or not), if I don't know how many indentations I need before hand?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- If you want to make custom styles to each level** then ">" will be good for you, ">" only choose the direct child.

So you can choose the first level like this:

```
#theParentList > li
```

The second level will be

```
#theParentList > li > ul > li
```

The third:

```
#theParentList > li > ul > li > ul > li
```

Etc..

**2- However if you want to make levels to shift a little to the right and you don't have independent styles to every level**, then you can apply this css:

```
#theParentList li {
    margin-left: 2em; 
}
```

This will effect all "li" children and grandchildren...
so Every li will be shifted a little to the right from it's parent and will shift all it's children with it.

Notice: if you want to make it start shifting from level 2 then you can put another "li" like this:

```
#theParentList li li {
    margin-left: 2em; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I do it problematically? For the sake of argument, lets say there are 10 levels. It would be inconvenient for me to hard code 10 different CSS blocks with different margins/padding. Can the padding be done programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: I thought you want to make independent styles for levels.
If you want to make it shifts a little with every level then you can make it with css like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hphvpxuo/2/

Comment: Thanks man. Marking as answer. But, could you please elaborate on "how" it works? Please see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hphvpxuo/4/. In this, you have the new "#theParentList li li" block that appears to work for all of them.. How can this work for all the indentations?! Also, now, the mouse hovering doesn't work properly. The parents don't hover correctly, and when the grand/great grand children are hovered, the whole block is highlighted. Can that be prevented?

Comment: @Phoneniyx I modified it for your answer :)

Comment: for the hover issue you can just replace (li li:hover) selector with (li div:hover) selector in your code

Comment: Awesome thanks! :). Also, I fixed the mouse hover issue - http://jsfiddle.net/hphvpxuo/7/ - by adding a new tag to each "data" entry and specifying the hover effect based on that (but, yours is better). Btw, in the padding formatting "#theParentList li li", the HTML actually has a "ul" between any  two "li" entries in two levels. Why is that ok? (clearly it works, but I was curious). I always thought the CSS code should mirror the tag sequence exactly to find a match... i.e. "#theParentList li ul li" (which also works).

Comment: No need for ul, as I said it'll take any child or grandchild in any depth. so no need for sequence if you don't use ">".

Take a look at this page for more information http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/